# Regular expression to replace &amp; with & in XML file

Tags: asp.net, regex

In an XML file, I am capturing a long list of URLS from a web page, using regex (in .NET).  Within the captured URLS, I simply need to substitute '&' for all '`&amp;`' that are located within the URLS. How do I do this?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this is impossible to answer without knowing the format of the file.

Comment: regex seems a bit overkill for replacing one character. Surely you can just do a string search & replace.

Comment: @Sam Hasler: It looks to me like he only wants to replace '&' if it's in a URL. Which is nearly impossible, but perhaps not if the URLs are delimited in some fashion.

Comment: I ment to say replace "&amp;" with "&" My xml file is a web service parser that I am running to capture URLs. For example: once I capture a list of URLs, the &amp; within the URLS just need to be replaced with & so the parser can move on to capture the next set of URLs. The entity &amp; is making it impossible to capture the next set in my parser. I am using Expresso as my tool, but I can't figure out how to build and expression to replace that one symbol in multiple URLs.

Comment: A recent suggestion.....to use backreferences....which I also have no experienc with...

Answer (score 1):

If you do this and save the results, you'll be left with **invalid** xml.  If you are using a real xml parser the `&amp;` will be correctly returned as `&` at the time you read it.

If you insist on proceeding, a simple `String.Replace("&amp;", "&")` on each url should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a regex I'd suggest using the `String.Replace("&","&amp;")` string function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do just:

```
string.Join("\n", System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")).Replace("&", "&amp;");
```

?